# Jooq querying tables with soft delete

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I want to write soft-delete records instead of hard-deleting them in jooq. But what about querying tables with soft delete?

So I dont want to write

```
SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE DELETED=false
```

But instead I want just to write

```
SELECT id, name FROM users
```

Answer (score 0):

We currently do not support this sort of SQL transformation out of the box, but you can extend jOOQ using a `VisitListener`. Soft deletion is a simpler case of row level security as described in this blog post here:
https://blog.jooq.org/implementing-client-side-row-level-security-with-jooq

One example approach how to implement this would be to add an interface to all generated tables, if they have a `DELETED` column:

```
interface SoftDeletable {
    TableField<? Boolean> deleted();
}
```

And then match that in your `VisitListener`, adding a predicate in case the `FROM` clause contains a reference to this table. You could then also make this work for aliased tables, derived tables, etc.

We're working on improving jOOQ's internal query object model in jOOQ 3.13 and future releases, such that these use cases are easier to implement than with a `VisitListener`. Specifically, support for soft deletion is on our roadmap: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2683

Comment: Soft deletes no longer seem to be on JOOQ's roadmap, based on the comment thread. Is this still an accurate comment?

Comment: @ChristianGruber: What made you think so?

Comment: The continual removal from milestones and adding to the next milestone, with comments in the thread pointing out that it is deprioritized. I'm not saying it's never going to happen, but that's how I read the comment thread on issue #2683. I may have misread. Happy to be wrong. (I have no stake in it one way or another, just what I interpreted)

Comment: @ChristianGruber: The moving of milestones doesn't mean anything. Yes, it's been taken into consideration for a few times and postponed, but that doesn't mean we won't do it. It's such a great feature to have, why not do it eventually? But if we had done it before [jOOQ 3.16's new model API overhaul](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/) and the [included SQL transformation capabilities](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/model-api-replacement/), it would have been a big mistake.

Comment: @ChristianGruber: It's a very complex feature in jOOQ. We don't want to just replace `record.delete()` by `record.update()` like some ORM. We want to transform *every* SQL query from `DELETE` to `UPDATE` and from `SELECT` to `SELECT .. WHERE NOT deleted`. This includes all sorts of subqueries, views, CTE, etc. etc. Before 3.16, it would have been *very hard* to get right. Now, it will be possible.